# How to align a pspicture to the center of page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pstricks

I have a pspicture inside a figure:

```
\begin{pspicture}(40,25)
\psframe(0,0)(30,20)
\end{pspicture}
```

The frame is displayed at the top-left of the page. Is it possible to automatically move it to the center of the page?

The pstricks user's guide mentions a baseline argument, but this seems to be a vertical baseline, not a horizontal one.

Comment: If you *just* want a frame of a particular size, there's no need for using `\psframe` inside a `pspicture` environment. Is this a specific requirement? For example, do you have something more complex inside the `pspicture`?

Comment: Yes, there are other objects inside. I just created a MWE.

Comment: ...and by "center of the page" are you referring to the horizontal center? If so, @Herbert's answer is probably what you're after (use `\centering` though instead of the `center` environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `shift=*` it can be shifted vertically to be centered to the base line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=1mm}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\_
\begin{pspicture}(40,25)
\psframe(0,0)(30,20)
\end{pspicture}
\_
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\_
\begin{pspicture}[shift=*](40,25)
\psframe(0,0)(40,25)
\end{pspicture}
\_
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]